# AWS CDK Grab Nested Stack for Pipeline Test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I am writing unit tests in AWS-CDK for a pipeline that has multiple stages / stacks that are being deployed cross account.  Within each stage, there is a stack that gets generated that I need to get the cloud formation of that template.  I have this in a snapshot test now to verify the template but this only contains the parent / pipeline stack with the stage definition, not the actual stage stack.  In the pipeline stack, I see the below for the stage which i need to get the template / template configuration from the stack to synth it.  Is there a way to synth this into a template to get the information?

```
},
    "StackName": "mystagestack-deploy-mgmt-stack",
    "TemplateConfiguration": "Synth_Output::assembly-IntegrationRepoStack/mystagestack-deploy-mgmt-stack.template.json.config.json",
    "TemplatePath": "Synth_Output::assembly-IntegrationRepoStack/mystagestack-deploy-mgmt-stack.template.json",
},
```

Thanks
Nick

Comment: What specifically do you want, the template of the stack?

Comment: Yes.  So, in this case, when the parent synths, want to get the template / stack that is referenced here to dump out the snapshot / validation and add unit tests for it.

Comment: `cdk synth -o ./output_folder PipelineStack/StageName/ParentStack/NestedStackA`

Comment: yeah, this is during synth stage, I am doing this as part of testing.  So, would be in either 'npx cdk test' or 'yarn test' beofre this is fully synth'd / generated.  The above example is a integration stack / pipleine I have for a stage test so can see it is generating the output, just need to be able to grab that output.

Comment: I guess as a follow on, is there a way in the cloudformation-include (CfnInclude) to grab the current stack value, then load nested stack in that / output them to another variable?

Comment: The only way to get a template is to run `cdk synth`

Comment: Yeah, since this is in the testing stage / not a full template, was hoping to find a way to get it from the integration stack that I created for the stage and not the full template from a full synth.

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for `Template.fromStack(myStack)` -- this returns a synthesized Template object that you can then make detailed assertions about.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html#testing_fine_grained

Comment: Hey Nate, thanks for the follow up.  In terms of the template.FromStack option, since the stack in reference 'mystagestack-deploy-mgmt-stack' is part of the test stack that is being generated, can I get that stack as a separate item?

Comment: Yes -- `Template.fromStack` will synthesize an entire stack, including nested stacks. If you only want to synthesize a particular nested stack,  you can instantiate it separately and just call `fromStack` on that specific stack.